# Difference between AbstractController and ActionController in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the difference between `AbstractController` and `ActionController` in `rails 4`.
What do they do and how they differ ?

Answer (score 4):

`AbstractController` provides the structure and `ActionController` is one implementation of that structure concerning web related rendering.

At the core of the `AbstractController` is the `render` method. The abstract controller lays out what are the things need to happen in as generic way as possible (normalize arguments, process formats etc), but it does not concern itself with any of the specifics.

`ActionController` is a specific implementation of that `AbstractController`. The `ActionController::Base` class provides a `render` method that added specific `web` flavor. It concerns itself to things like `request`, `response`, `http`, which do not exist in `AbstractController`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

`AbstractController::Base` is a low-level API. Nobody should be using it directly, and subclasses (like `ActionController::Base`) are expected to provide their own render method, since rendering means different things depending on the context.

This was taken directly from the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Base.html

Comment: Benjamin Tan yes I know, the point of this answer is to get some explanation to suplement `rails api`...